# Fastest way of send a bunch of http requests

Tags: http, https, python-requests

So I am building an app that needs to scrape a bunch of data from a bunch of websites and I was wondering what's the fastest way to do it? I am open to all suggestions, all programming languages and all methods as hard as they are as long as there is atleast any information about them. The fastest speed I've managed to achieve so far is 1000 requests in 300ms with rust on a local host.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hyper library for the HTTP requests is the fastest way to send asynchronous requests. It is a low-level library and offers both client and server-side APIs.
Here’s how to make a GET request using Hyper. First, create a new client object, then pass it a URL from which to retrieve data. Next, use the new await syntax Rust supports to await the response.

```
let client = Client::new();

// Parse an `http::Uri`...
let uri = "http://httpbin.org/ip".parse()?;

// Await the response...
let resp = client.get(uri).await?;

println!("Response: {}", resp.status());
```